# Game database - Categorizing games by console

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I'm working on a database which contains a lot of console games. As for right now, it only has `gameid`, `title`, `imgcover`, `publisher` and `releasedate`. I am retrieving the games from the database and displaying them using DataList. However, I want to be able to display games that only belongs to one or more consoles (e.g. PS4 and Xbox One). What would be the best way to define which consoles each game is available for? I'm quite new to databases, so the only things I can think of is having a true/false column for each console for each game, but that just sounds like a horrible way of doing it. Should I create tables for each console and simply list the `gameid` and `title` there, or is there an easier and more efficient way of doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would do it two different ways.

1. Create a Console Table and have entries related to all consoles.

   1.1.  Create a Game_Console Table and have entries related to Gameid and Consoleid as a Key, so that duplicates are not possible.

   1.2  Join Game and Console using Game_Console to retrieve data faster by using possible indexes as well.

or

1. Have another column called Console in the same game table and have data with comma separated values like XBOX360, PS3, XBOXONE, PS4(etc).

   1.1 Write a user defined function to split the Comma separated value. See this article I wrote for splitting a string http://sqlsaga.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server/

That's pretty much you can do about it unless you have other ways in mind.